# how to split a nested dictionary inside a column of a dataframe into new rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
01   ABC  {'link':'http://smthing1}
02   DEF  {'link':'http://smthing2}
```

I need to split col3 into new rows:
expected output dataframe :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
01   ABC  'http://smthing1'
02   DEF  'http://smthing2'
```

This doesnt seem to work :

```
df= df.apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Is the dtype of col3 string or object? That is, does it contain a JSON-like string, or an actual dict?

Comment: dtype is  object

Comment: @Anti_cse51 and what does `df['Col3'].map(type).value_counts()` show?

Comment: <class 'float'>    49
<class 'str'>       1   @JonClements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), but first convert to dictionaries if necessary:

```
#converting to dicts
#import ast
#df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['Col3'] = df['Col3'].str.get('link')
```

Comment: ast.literal_eval saved the day

Answer (score 0):

If you like long code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [[1,   'ABC',  {'link':'http://smthing1'}],  # list 
[2,   'DEF',  {'link':'http://smthing2'}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) #convert to pandas dataframe

convert_col3_to_dict = dict(df['col3']) #convert string to dict 

list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    elements = my_list[i][:2]
    #remove empty list
    elements = [x for x in elements if x != []]
    # print(elements)
    list1.append(elements)

for key, val in convert_col3_to_dict.items(): #Iterating through the col3
for k,v in val.items(): #iterating through values in col3
    # print([v]) # printing the value
    list2.append([v])

new_list = []

for f, b in zip(list1, list2):
    # print(f, b)
    tem_list = f + b
    new_list.append(tem_list)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_list, columns=['col1', 'clo2', 'col3'])

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
   col1 clo2             col3
0     1  ABC  http://smthing1
1     2  DEF  http://smthing2
```